# Windows 10 Disconnecting monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a rather strange problem with my monitor setup at the moment. I have an HP Z Book with Windows 10 (20H2 still) from work. When working from home I use an Sitecom multiport adapter to connect 2 external monitors via HDMI.
Since my workspace is limited, my laptop is closed on my desk. So I only use the external monitors.

Sometimes, my monitors loose connection. Specially when browsing to a website that is showing video. Not all the time, but sometimes. I tried with different browsers already to see if that is the issue. But happens with Edge, Brave and Chrome.
To give an example, when I go to Netflix with any of these browser I usually get the issue when starting a video.
The problem does not occur when I use the Windows 10 app for Netflix. So that makes me think it's related to the browser.

The problem however does not occur when I have my laptop open. That's the setup I use when going to work. Never had any issues there. But I use an HP docking at work.
Has anybody seen this behaviour before? I'm not sure how to debug this problem

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the adapter at home is just not compatible or the GPU got an issue. It sound strange but I have encountered multiple GPU issues related to HP and Dell (at this point it's all HP) PCs and Notebooks.

It's not directly related to your issue but the most common issue I have encountered is that some program windows get a white border on the top when maximized and they only work properly when on the other screen or in non-maximized mode. You can move them with the shortcut Windows Key + Arrow (Up, Down, Left & Right).

Usually a GPU driver update solves such issues until it reappears after X weeks or months. It also only happens on some PCs. Like 1 or 2 out of 20.

Another thing you can try is to press Windows Key + Shift + Ctrl + B. This reinitializes the GPU and might temporarily solve your issue. Same goes for a restart obviously.

Yet another option might be to just get the same adapter for at home that you have at work.

Comment: Seems that the issue is worse depending on which USB-C port I use on my pc. Maybe I should update the drivers?

Comment: Yes the driver update should help. Also do you know if your laptop has a USB-C and a thunderbolt port? In a previous job, we had laptops with 2 ports. One was mainly to charge the laptop and the other one was for devices only without charging. We never told people to use one port over the other but they just always placed it in the right port. Try using the same port every time and observe if one port has more issues over another. Also perhaps there are specific drivers for your non HP docking station at home. The issue could be due to a change in FPS needed. Test a 60-120 FPS video on youtube

Comment: Indeed, I never really noticed. But one of the port has a lightning bolt icon next to it. So probably that is a thunderbolt port. I'll always use this one from now on since that is the one that works best anyway. :-) Thanks for the help. I'll update some drivers and see what that gives!

Comment: Sounds like a solid plan. Consider marking the answer once you can say that there have been no further issues with your monitors since the changes. ;)